# Convert.FromBase64String() failing in Vista SP2 compatibility mode

Tags: c#, windows-vista, visual-foxpro

We have a VFP POS application that uses a C# DLL for displaying and printing BMP images generated from captured signature data. The data itself is sent from VFP via STRCONV(bSignatureData,1) to the C# library which then performs Convert.FromBase64String() on the passed byte data. Below is the data that the DLL is receiving:

```
/////wICMQT+ATYE+AFBBO0BVQTnAV8E3QFzBNgBgwTYAYcE4AGGBOgBgAQCAmcEFAJWBD4CKgRrAvsDgQLkA6gCuwO5AqsDxgKeA9YCkQPYApUD1AKdA84CqAO8AskDsQLdA5cCCwR7Aj0EbgJVBGMCawRRApAETAKdBE8CpwRXAqQEcwKOBIYCfAScAmkEygI9BPcCEQQKA/0DKgPeAz0DzQNCA8oDRAPKA0ID1QM5A+oDMwP3AycDFwQbAzgEFgNJBBMDVwQVA2wEGQNxBCEDcwQ7A2sEXQNWBHEDRwSYAygEqwMZBLsDCwTXA/UD5gPrA+oD6wPsA+0D6AP7A+ADEgTcAx8E0gM8BM8DSgTMA1cEywNtBNADegTVA3wE4wN5BOsDdQT8A2oEBQRkBBQEWwQcBFkEIwRZBDQEXgRKBGgEWARtBH0EdASSBHUE/////w==
```

My tech department informs me that some of our clients need to run our application in Vista SP2 compatibility mode to work properly (maybe a Win10 thing?). When launched in this compatibility mode, the C# convert throws an exception stating that the data passed is not a valid Base64 string. However, when the application is not run in compatibility mode, everything works fine.

Any ideas as to what Vista SP2 mode is lacking?

Comment: Are you sure sure the problem is there?

Comment: The first thing I would do, debugging-wise, would be to create a brand new project that attempts to call `Convert.FromBase64String`, using the data above as a test string. Run this in Vista compatibility mode and see if it bombs. If so, start debugging. If not, then the DLL probably isn't returning the string you expect, so your problem is elsewhere.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this problem.

Comment: Because the `Convert.FromBase64String` seems to be written in vanilla C#, by looking at it (on my pc) with ILSpy, without system calls.

Comment: @xanatos - Could you further explain what you mean by that method being written in vanilla C#?

Comment: @GS-Scooter That a crash dependant on the OS is normally connected on using some API of the OS. But the `Convert.FromBase64String` doesn't use any API. It is C# code that you could write.

Comment: Thanks everyone - was just able to confirm that the call from VFP was the culprit and not the C# DLL.

Comment: How could you reason that? You are not passing a Base64 encoded value from VFP in the first place. You are passing a conversion a value that is converted to DBCS, How come you get a value that looks like a base64 string???? VFP works perfectly well with base64 encodings on any OS I remember in windows history since StrConv() and base64 conversion was introduced. I also use it with VFP and C# and have no problem. Did you try 13 instead of 1 with StrConv()? It is the enumeration value for converting to base64 encoded.